# What does url in simple_form do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In the simple_form bootstrap example code, there is a reference to **url: create_horizontal_examples_url** in the form.

What is this url for?

https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/examples/_horizontal_form_sf.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_horizontal, url: create_horizontal_examples_url, as:  'user_horizontal', html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },
  wrapper: :horizontal_form,
  wrapper_mappings: {
    check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :horizontal_file_input,
    boolean: :horizontal_boolean
  } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the url that the form data is submitted to.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Why would this be necessary: the Rails controller and action already contain this information. Is it some kind of override?

Comment: The browser needs to know where to send the data. The default for form_for (and simple_form_for) is to use the @var assigned to the form to generate the submit url. The :url option is used when the url you want is different from what rails would generate, or when the var is not a model instance and therefor can't be determined.

Comment: OK that makes sense. It's not clear in the simple_form documents.